# Integrate 2-Form over the boundary of the standard cube

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

> Find the integral of the form $dy∧dz+dz∧dx$ over the boundary of the standard cube in $R^3$.

My thought: consider $\omega =y dz+ z dx$ so that $d\omega =dy∧dz+dz∧dx$

That is by Stokes, we have $$ \int_{I^3} d\omega =\int_{\partial I^3} \omega $$
I don't know how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're misusing Stokes here. Your $\omega$ is a 1-form, so you can't integrate it over $\partial I^3$,which is a 2-dimensional object. Rather, you should let $\omega=dy\wedge dz+dz\wedge dx$. Now, what is $d\omega$? So, what is $\int_{\partial I^3}\omega$?

Comment: I'm not sure, is it just zero? so $\omega$ is closed.

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: So, what is the importance of the cube? I mean if $d\omega=0$ then does it follow  that $\int_{\partial M} \omega =0$ for any $M$ ??

Comment: that's exactly right (assuming all the hypotheses of Stokes' theorem are satisfied of course). There's nothing special about the cube $I^3$.